# How to add a new trace while removing the last one?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am new to shiny and plotly. What I'm trying to do is to add a trace first and then I want it to be replaced by a new one every time I click on a button.

here is my minimal example:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(plotlyOutput("fig1"),
                
                numericInput("A",
                             label = h5("A"),
                             value = "",
                             width = "100px"),
                numericInput("B",
                             label = h5("B"),
                             value = "",
                             width = "100px"),
                actionButton("action3", label = "Add to plot"),
                actionButton("action4", label = "Remove point")
                
                
                )
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  A <- 1:5
  B <- c(115, 406, 1320, 179, 440)
  data <- data.frame(A, B)
  
  fig <- plot_ly(data, x = A, y = B, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')
  
  output$fig1 <- renderPlotly(fig)
  
  observeEvent(input$action3, {
    vals <- reactiveValues(A = input$A, B = input$B)
    plotlyProxy("fig1") %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("addTraces", 
                        list(x = c(vals$A,vals$A),
                             y = c(vals$B,vals$B),
                             type = "scatter",
                             mode = "markers"
                             
                        )
      )
  })
  observeEvent(input$action4, {
    vals <- reactiveValues(A = input$A, B = input$B)
    plotlyProxy("fig1") %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("deleteTraces")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

I can add a new trace easily but they all remain on the plot.
My solution was to add a new button to delete the trace but it did not work.
I have already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138568/removing-traces-by-name-using-plotlyproxy-or-accessing-output-schema-in-reactiv/53831080#53831080) but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you described, it sounds like you want to add a trace and remove the most recent trace added at the same time when the button is pressed. This would still leave the original plot/trace that you started with.

I tried simplifying a bit. The first `plotlyProxyInvoke` will remove the most recently added trace (it is zero-indexed, leaving the first plotly trace in place).

The second `plotlyProxyInvoke` will add the new trace. Note that the (x, y) pair is included twice based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50773687/3460670).

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

A <- 1:5
B <- c(115, 406, 1320, 179, 440)
data <- data.frame(A, B)

ui <- fluidPage(plotlyOutput("fig1"),
                numericInput("A",
                             label = h5("A"),
                             value = "",
                             width = "100px"),
                numericInput("B",
                             label = h5("B"),
                             value = "",
                             width = "100px"),
                actionButton("action3", label = "Add to plot"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  fig <- plot_ly(data, x = A, y = B, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers')
  
  output$fig1 <- renderPlotly(fig)
  
  observeEvent(input$action3, {
    plotlyProxy("fig1", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("deleteTraces", list(as.integer(1)))
    plotlyProxy("fig1", session) %>%
      plotlyProxyInvoke("addTraces", 
                        list(x = c(input$A, input$A),
                             y = c(input$B, input$B),
                             type = 'scatter',
                             mode = 'markers')
      )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I wanted to do although I did not understand the list(as.integer(1) or the "zero- index" as you said.

Comment: "zero-indexed" refers to the numbering system used with `plotly`, starting 0, 1, 2...instead of with R which is one-indexed or 1, 2, 3...etc. So in this case, you include which trace to delete, since it is zero-indexed, the first trace is trace 0, second trace is trace 1, etc. Since you already have your first trace with 5 points, the second trace is the single point added, or trace 1, which is removed. I noticed that the other examples used `as.integer()` so I assumed that an integer was needed for the index (technically 1 is `double` not `integer`)...and structure needed is `list`...